# Can't figure out limit of a function with a square root

Tags: limits, functions

I am trying to find the limit of the following function when $x$ tends to $-\infty$:

$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} \frac {x+1}{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}}$$

When I factor by the highest term in the numerator and the denominator, I keep on finding 1 which is not the right answer when I look at the graph which seems to indicate that -1 is the right answer.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be careful with the sign, since $\sqrt{x^2}=\color{red}{|x|=-x}$ when $x$ is negative.

For $x<0$, you have:

$$\frac{x+1}{\sqrt{x^2-x+1}} = \frac{x+1}{\color{red}{|x|}\sqrt{1-\tfrac{1}{x}+\tfrac{1}{x^2}}} =  \frac{x\left( 1+\tfrac{1}{x} \right)}{\color{red}{-x}\sqrt{1-\tfrac{1}{x}+\tfrac{1}{x^2}}}$$
Now you can cancel $x$ and take the limit.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

As  $x<0,$  choose $-1/x=h\implies h\to0^+, h>0$

$$x+1=1+x=1-\dfrac1h=\dfrac{h-1}h$$

$$x^2-x+1=\dfrac{1-h+h^2}{h^2}\implies\sqrt{x^2-x+1}=\dfrac{\sqrt{1+h+h^2}}{\sqrt{h^2}}$$

Now as $h$ is real, $\sqrt{h^2}=|h|$

As $h>0,|h|=+h$